# TestCafe - Error : Cannot establish one or more browser connections

Tags: node.js, testing, npm, testcafe, browser-automation

Testcafe was able to connect browser and trigger test cases before. All of sudden, it stopped working. The main issue is test cafe is able to open browser but it's not connecting to browser and unable to hit URL. Browser is getting opened and being closed by itself after some time. Browser shows following message.

---

This site can’t be reached XXX.XXX.X.XX took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

---

I didn't make any changes to softwares except changing my machine's login password. I changed the password in all required places like .npmrc etc.

Appreciate your help if anyone can provide solution.

**Software versions:**

node -v
v14.17.5

npm -v
7.20.5

testcafe -v

Using locally installed version of TestCafe.

1.15.2

**command to trigger my tests** : testcafe chrome test.js

**Note:** This issue happening for all browsers.

**Error** : ERROR Cannot establish one or more browser connections.
1 of 1 browser connections have not been established:

- chrome

Hints:

- Increase the value of the "browserInitTimeout" option if it is too low (currently: 2 minutes for local browsers and 6 minutes for remote browsers). This option determines how long TestCafe waits for browsers to be ready.
- The error can also be caused by network issues or remote device failure. Make sure that your network connection is stable and you can reach the remote device.

Comment: It looks like your website is not reachable via the network. Try opening your testing page without testcafe on the same computer where you run your testcafe tests. If the page is reachable, I suggest you [create an issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md) in the TestCafe GitHub repository and add required information and sample code so that we reproduce the issue. If you can't share the info publicly, please send it to support@devexpress.com.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I sent an email to devexpress with all the details.

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions, owner and group in /tmp/Crashpad